# std::memory_order for std::atomic<T>::wait

Tags: c++, atomic, c++20, memory-barriers

According to cppreference, in C++20 there are `wait`, `notify_one`, `notify_all` in `std::atomic<T>`. Looks like they make `std::atomic<T>` usable as a *futex*.

I'm asking why does `wait` accept std::memory_order as a parameter. As I always need to check if waking from wait is not spurious, I'll specify the memory order in corresponding load:

```
  std::atomic<bool> x;

  while (x.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == false)
  {
     x.wait(false, std::memory_order_acquire);
  }
```

Or should I specify `std::memory_order_relaxed` for wait? Are there scenarios with `wait` not followed by `load`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this issue to GitHub for this proposal, and got [a response](https://github.com/brycelelbach/wg21_p1135_cpp20_synchronization_library/issues/14) that std::atomic::wait is meant to be implemented on a futex with logic over it, specifically to mask spurious wakes.

So, [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/atomic/atomic/wait) is wrong about this:

> These functions are allowed to unblock spuriously, i.e. return due to reasons other than value change or notification.

And while loop is superfluous in my example, I should use just:

```
std::atomic<bool> x;

x.wait(false, std::memory_order_acquire);
```

Answer (score 3):

All atomic operations on the same object will always have a single order, and the order within a single thread is included in that. That is, `relaxed` cannot reorder atomic operations on the same object within the same thread.

The `relaxed` memory order is the order relative to other memory operations besides that specific atomic one. So `relaxed` is fine for checking for the wait itself, but when you want to actually read data which written by the releasing thread that *isn't* contained in the atomic value, you'll need a stronger memory order in order to ensure their visibility. So your outer loop should use a more appropriate condition for acquiring visibility, should it be necessary.

Comment: I see your point, but then I want an example when `std::memory_order_relaxed` for wait is not sufficient. I mean, why does `wait` have `std::memory_order` parameter at all, could it have assumed `std::memory_order_relaxed` always used?